# django template if condition

Tags: django, django-templates

got a question here.

I have the following

```
{% if form.tpl.yes_no_required == True  %}
             <!-- path 1 -->
{% else %}
    {% if form.tpl.yes_no_required == False %}

        <!-- path 2 -->
    {% endif %} 
{% endif %}
```

The value for form.tpl.yes_no_required is None, but I was routed to path 2. Can anyone please explain why is this so? EDIT: if the value is none, i do not want it display anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use the template language to test against what you think are constants, the parser is actually testing 2 "literals".

The parser tests for 2 literals with names 'None' and 'False'.
When parser tries to resolve these in the context a VariableDoesNotExist exception is thrown and both objects resolve to the python value None
and None == None.

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t = Template("{% if None == False %} not what you think {% endif %}")
c = Context({"foo": foo() })
```

prints u' not what you think '

```
c = Context({'None':None})
t.render(c)
```

prints u' not what you think '

```
c = Context({'None':None, 'False':False})
t.render(c)
```

prints u''

Answer (score 1):

None != False None != True also ...
do some things like this for none item

```
{% if form.tpl.yes_no_required  %}
             <!-- path 1 -->
{% else %}
    {% if not form.tpl.yes_no_required %}

        <!-- path 2 -->
    {% endif %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I wanted my code to not go into path 2, but strangely my code went into path 2.

Comment: @amateur you can in python check it and if is none type change it to False

Comment: actually i needed all 3 values, true false and none.

Comment: @amateur so check it here with 
{% if form.tpl.yes_no_required  %} ... its None or not