# Incorrect work of if-else statement in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this code:

```
{% if username_is_ok == True %}
    <input type="text" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
{% else %}
    <div class="control-group error">
        <input type="text" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" value="{{ username }}"
               class="text-error" required>
        <span class="help-block text-error">User already exists</span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And debugger says that `username_is_ok == True` equals `{bool} True`. But it goes to the `else` branch and when page loads I see the error message. I can't see no mistakes and I feel frustrated about that. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: try using `{% if username_is_ok %}`

Comment: I've added `== True` in order to doublecheck value of `username_is_ok`, so this is not a solution.

Comment: Did you check that `username_is_ok` equals True??

Comment: @nnaelle he said he did in his question.

Comment: Oh i thought that he just checked if it was a bool. my bad then. I would check in the views anyways, just in case. Sorry i misunderstood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django templating language is not Python but rather its own custom "templating language" with minimal logic (this is by design: it's encouraged that you keep "controller" logic away from templates). Therefore, you'll find that some valid Python may not be valid template syntax

In your example, the templating language tries to evaluate "True" as a literal. Since you probably didn't define a key named "True" in the context, a `VariableDoesNotExist` exception is raised, and the template treats the value as the python `None` type.

The debugger evaluates the conditional as Python, not Django templating language, and so the value is tested against the Python `True` and evaluates to `True`

In order for the logic to work, you might want to try adding `True` to your template context. Something like: `{"True": True}`

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672415/927229